# How do I make user defined empty default constructor behave like compiler defined empty constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization

I've been trying to learn C++ for about a month and it still puzzles me. For example this 'easy' code:

```
class A
{
    int m;
public:
    A() = default;
    int getM() { return m; }
};

class B
{
    int m;
public:
    // empty body and empty initializer list
    B() {} // isn't this the same as "B() = default;" ?
    int getM() { return m; }

};

int main()
{
    A a1;
    A a2{};

    std::cout << "a1.m=" << a1.getM() << "\n";
    std::cout << "a2.m=" << a2.getM() << "\n";

    B b1;
    B b2{};

    std::cout << "b1.m=" << b1.getM() << "\n";
    std::cout << "b2.m=" << b2.getM() << "\n";

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

result:

```
a1.m=...garbage
a2.m=0
b1.m=...garbage
b2.m=...garbage
```

According to [CPP REFERENCE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) default constructor defined by the compiler does have empty body and empty initializer list. So how the heck does it (in class A) initialize member 'm' to zero when explicitly defined default constructor with empty body and empty initializer list does not. According to cppreference excerpt:

```
If the implicitly-declared default constructor is not defined as deleted,  it is defined (that is, a function body is generated and compiled)
by the compiler if odr-used, and it has exactly the same effect as a user-defined constructor with empty body and empty initializer list.
```

As far as I understand it both constructors should behave exactly the same way. Seems simple yet I do not get it.

Comment: I think `A a2{};` is doing member-wise initialization.

Comment: @user4581301 it has to be C++11 or higher, or `A a2{};` and `B b2{};` would not compile, C++98/03 only accepted the form of `A a2 = {}`. You should put it up as the answer.

Comment: I still don't get it - cppreference says explicitly that defaulted constructor is empty and its initializer list is also empty - so how is this member initialized to zero by compiler provided constructor if it is empty with empty initializer list?

Comment: I compile it as c++14

Comment: The duplicate [Is it guaranteed that defaulted constructor initialize built in types automatically to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441087/is-it-guaranteed-that-defaulted-constructor-initialize-built-in-types-automatica) is close but not a very not a very good duplicate. Both exploit [Zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization), but the dupe doesn't explain the crux of the question: Why `A` works and `B` doesn't. I've removed the hold.

Comment: OK, everyone: `A` is not an aggregate (due to `A::m` being private), so it cannot be aggregate initialization.

Comment: You know, I'm just going to run this through MSVC14 and see what I get.

Comment: In debug I get `a1.m=-858993460
a2.m=0
b1.m=-858993460
b2.m=-858993460` Note the "garbage" values all being identical. in Release however, I get `a1.m=0
a2.m=0
b1.m=0
b2.m=0`

Comment: ah, here's the point of confusion, it's not aggregate-initialization, it's the supertype, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: And the point of note: *If the braced-init-list is empty and T is a class type with a **default** constructor, value-initialization is performed.*

Comment: And value initialization on a class with an explicitly-deleted default constructor zero initializes if construction is trivial.

Comment: Basically, the `default` c'tor does work as if it were empty, but list-initialization uses the `default`ing to trigger value-initialization which is not actually a function of the `default` c'tor itself, and which the user-defined c'tor does not perform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the basic idea. Both `A a2{};` and `B b2{};` will perform what is called "[value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)" on the two objects. However, the way value initialization behaves depends on how those types are defined.

`B` is an object which has a user-provided default constructor. "User-provided" being the term for when you provide a body for the default constructor. Because of that, value initialization will call the default constructor. That default constructor does not initialize its members, so the members remain uninitialized.

`A` is an object which does not have a user-provided default constructor. Nor does it have any other user-provided constructors. And the default constructor is not deleted either. And there are no default member initializers in `A`. Given all of that, value initialization will perform *zero initialization* on the object. Which means that it will write all zeros to the memory for that object before it comes into existence.

That's what the rules say; the two do not behave the same, nor are they meant to. Nor is there anything you can do to make a user-provided default constructor act like a defaulted default constructor in *all* cases. You can make the user-provided constructor value initialize its members, but it would do so all the time, even if you use default initialization (`B b1;`, for example).

Why do the rules say that? Because `= default` is *not supposed to* be equivalent to an empty constructor body. Indeed, being different is why `= default` *exists* as a feature.

When you `= default` your default constructor, you are saying "generate the default constructor as you normally would". This is important, because there are things you can do which actively prevent the compiler from generating a default constructor for you. If you specify other constructors (which are not copy/move constructors), the compiler will not automatically generate one. So by using `= default` syntax, you're telling the compiler that you want the generated default constructor.

By contrast, if you make an empty body in your default constructor, you are saying something totally different. You are explicitly saying, "If a user calls my default constructor, I *want* my members to be default-initialized." That's what it means when you have an empty member initializer list in a constructor, after all. So that's what it should do.

If `= default` and an empty body behaved the same, there would be no way for you to get that behavior, to say that you want default initialization of your members no matter what.

Basically, Cppreference's statement is completely wrong; it does not have "exactly the same effect as a user-defined constructor with empty body and empty initializer list". Nor is it supposed to.

---

If you want to understand the thinking of value initialization a bit further, consider this.

```
int i{};
```

That is guaranteed to produce a value of 0 for `i`. It is therefore reasonable that this:

```
struct S{int i;};
S s{};
```

Should *also* produce a value of 0 for `s.i`. How does that happen? Because value initialization will zero-initialize `s`.

So how does a user say that they don't want that, or want some special form of initialization? You communicate that the same way you communicate everything else: you add a constructor. Specifically, a default constructor that does the form of initialization you want.

Comment: This is incorrect, *list-initialization* will only *value-initialize* a *non-aggregate* if the type has a `default` constructor.

Comment: @Tzalumen: Yes, and both types have default constructors.

Comment: No, you misunderstand, list-initialization looks for `default` specifically. if it sees an empty c'tor, it will not value-initialize. A has a `default` c'tor, B has an empty c'tor, A will value initialize during a list-initialization, B will not.

Comment: @Tzalumen: I don't know what you mean by a "`default` c'tor" as being distinct from an "empty c'tor". The [standard makes no such distinction.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#4) and [list initialization only says "is a class type with a default constructor"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#3.4) Perhaps you could use standard wording to explain.

Comment: Implementing an empty constructor body results in compilation differences, notably the lack of a defined copy c'tor which will cause special-case compilation errors with some STL operations.

Comment: @Tzalumen: "*Implementing an empty constructor body results in compilation differences*" An empty *default* constructor body, you mean. Yes, that is exactly the point I'm getting across: a default constructor defined as `= default` is not, nor is intended to be, the same as a default constructor with an empty body.

Comment: Also, if I was WRONG about `A() = default;` not being equivalent to `A() {}` during list-initialization, we wouldn't even be here, as the observed behavioral difference would not be present.

Comment: @Tzalumen: I don't understand what you're talking about. I'm saying that they are not equivalent. It's right there in the second, third, and fourth paragraphs. You are not wrong, nor am I wrong, because we're both *saying the same thing*. They both undergo value initialization, but what value initialization *does* is different.

Comment: Also `A() {}` is not an empty `default` c'tor. it is an empty `no-arg` c'tor, they are not the same thing. `default` is very specific to the implicit c'tor and the explicit `default`.

Comment: @Tzalumen: "*they are not the same thing.*" Yes, they are. It's [right there in the C++ standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#4): "A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X for which each parameter that is not a function parameter pack has a default argument (***including the case of a constructor with no parameters***)." Maybe you learned different terminology, but I'm speaking standard-ese.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191622/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-tzalumen).

Comment: I cannot use the chat system from this computer, it is policy restricted.

Comment: @Tzalumen: Well, I don't really want to get into a long thread argument about this, so please go spend some time with the C++ standard. I've given you some links; go look at them.

Comment: Your explanation does not explain why the RAII `A a1;` call to the defaulted no-arg c'tor produces different results vs the list-initialization of `A a2{};`. The defaulted no-arg is clearly not value-initializing the members, while list-initialization is.

Comment: @Tzalumen: It doesn't need to, because that's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: That is specifically part of what the user asked for, and was part of his code sample. If we're going to be pedantic, you didn't explain how to solve the headline question either.

Comment: @Tzalumen: No, the OP *mentioned* it; the OP did not ask about it. The OP's question is about the difference between defaulted default constructor and user-provided default constructor behavior. It's right there in the title. And mentioned again in text: "*So how the heck does it (in class A) initialize member 'm' to zero when explicitly defined default constructor with empty body and empty initializer list does not.*"

Comment: @Tzalumen: I added to paragraph 4 to more directly answer the title question.

Comment: From that link to the standard (15.1 §5), if you drop down to 15.1 §7, you'll find that a default c'tor as defined in §5 will not value-initialize its members (acts as an empty initializer list), which brings me back to the original situation, that **list-initialization** specifically is performing some kind of special check and treating a default-defined c'tor as different from an empty default c'tor.

Comment: @Tzalumen: And I explained exactly what that check is: it's called value initialization. Using `{}` on an object of class type [will perform value initialization on that object](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#3.4), and [value initialization does the check for user-provided vs. defaulted](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#8). It's all right there in my answer if you would just ***read it***.

Answer (score 2):

If any constructor is provided zero-initialization does not take place as stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)

> Zero initialization is performed in the following situations:
>
> ...
>
> 2) As part of value-initialization sequence for non-class types and for members of value-initialized class types **that have no constructors**, including value initialization of elements of aggregates for which no initializers are provided.

Also [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

> The effects of value initialization are:
>
> 1) **if T is a class type with at least one user-provided constructor of any kind, the default constructor is called;**

Which makes sense. One should be able to control whether any additional operations can be added. If you provide a constructor, you take responsibility for your object initializations.

Comment: Finally, an answer that explains the observed behavior.